# Error: the item you were attemping to purchase could not be found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm an android beginner. I created a test app which only got one button, and when you click on it, it starts the in-app purchase. It works couple of days earlier, but it was not working now. I also checked on other related post, I tried all the 'test account' and 'active in-app product' methods, but it still gives me the same error message.

Also, I tried to run the app directly from eclipse, it use to show me something like 'the version of your app can not make in-app purchase' since that APK was not signed. But today, I have the same error message again: The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

Please, some experienced android developer give me a hand.

Regards,

Jasen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a quick chat with Google. Google now requires the app to be published in order to test in-app billing.
So, we need to upload the app in alpha testing mode and test the in-app billing process.
Google has yet to review its documents so any of you guys having this sort of problem, hope it helps.

Comment: Pradino, i had the same issue and resolved it by publishing it as you suggested. You may accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this link when i implement inapp billing in my code and it is working fine till today so i hope it will help you

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: I tried, I create a new app, but it is still not working. Same error when I use the real in-app id.