# Have Google Changed In app Billing testing settings

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I ran into a problem today with one of my prototypes which uses IAB.

It is an unpublished app within my Developer Console the settings, signatures and SKUS have all been checked multiple times and are fine.

The app was working fully functional the last time it was tested around a month ago and now it returns the error from Google Play "Error: the item you were attemping to purchase could not be found". When a product is selected.

After much stress and research I found the following links below with similar problems.

[In App Billing - product not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586388/in-app-billing-product-not-found)

[Error: the item you were attemping to purchase could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750320/error-the-item-you-were-attemping-to-purchase-could-not-be-found)

[“The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found” Android in-app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918190/the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found-android-in-app-bil?lq=1)

[In App Billing - product not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586388/in-app-billing-product-not-found)

A few answers on these questions state that the application must now be published within the console.

Can anyone shed the light here as I need to do a presentation on this prototype with its usage of Googles IAB in a couple of days.

Thanks.

Comment: is your apk uploaded as a draft, i think you have to do that to test

Comment: Yes it is as I stated it was working fine before with the same steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they have changed their settings on the Developer Console you now must Publish your APK in Alpha to test IAB.

Its a bit of a pain if im honest as if you have game services you must upload high res images descriptions etc.

But after I published the APK In app purchases was working as expected again within a few hours.